# Display Custom Field in Sidebar if Value is Present

Tags: php, custom-field, sidebar

I'm trying to use 'if' 'else' to display a link button if I have a value in the 'TourURL' custom field, and if not, nothing will display but can't seem to get the if code to work:

```
<?php if(global $wp_query;
    $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
    echo get_post_meta($postid, 'TourURL', true);
    wp_reset_query();
): ?>
            <P>Show Link</P>

<?php else : ?>
            <P>No Link</P>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think, you're mistaken in how `if` works...?

```
$post_meta = get_post_meta(
    $GLOBALS['wp_query']->post->ID,
    'TourURL',
    true
);
if (! empty($post_meta)) echo '<p>Show Link</p>';
else echo '<p>No Link</p>';
```

This should do what you want - if I understood you correctly.

**// UPDATED**

Comment: Thanks (and sorry for the slow reply!)
When I use this code, the whole sidebar becomes empty...
Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Well, then sorry for my **really slow** reply. I must've overlooked your comment. Anyway, I updated the above code (and tested it). Now, it is working as expected, at least for me. What about you?